# How to use html in Woocommerce displayed fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use a fontawesome icon via HTML on a WooCommerce PHP add_fee, but it writes it down plainly...
How to make it work as an icon?

```
$text = 'Your discount <i class="fas fa-gift"></i>';
WC()->cart->add_fee( $text, $discount, true );
```

Being displayed literally as:

```
Your discount <i class="fas fa-gift"></i>
```

Comment: Looks like this gets explicitly treated as _text_ in the place where it gets actually output, so you’d need to find _that_ place, and modify the code there accordingly.

Comment: Yeah it is being escaped HTML, but ive found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, for anyone that will need it:

```
function show_an_icon_next_to_needed_fee_label( $safe_text, $text ){
    if( ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) && $text == 'LABEL TEXT HERE' ){
        $safe_text = $safe_text.'<span>HTML</span>';
    }
    return $safe_text;
}
add_filter( 'esc_html', 'show_an_icon_next_to_needed_fee_label', 10, 2 );
```